# AWS Lambda: 'MemorySize' value failed to satisfy constraint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a really weird problem while trying to change Lambda's memory size. It's clearly stated in the UI that we can **Set memory to between 128 MB and 10240 MB**, but when I set **8192** value and click **Apply**, I am getting the following error message:

> 'MemorySize' value failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have value less than or equal to 3008

Already checked the Quotas and it's all good there. Honestly, I am stuck

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

I got an answer from AWS support:

> Lambda functions with memory configuration greater than 3GB are currently unavailable for first time use in multiple regions. We are working on restoring this feature and mitigations are in progress. If you urgently require to use your function with memory greater than 3GB, please provide your account and region details so we can expedite access internally.

Comment: I'm surprised that AWS is having a capacity issue xD

Comment: What does "first time use in multiple regions" mean? We had successfully deployed a Lambda with 10GB memory in London in one account, then tried to migrate the stack to a different account in the same organisation in London region but this time cdk failed due to MemorySize capped at 3008. Strange

Answer (score 5):

3008 MB is the previous memory limit. Check out [this](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/aws-lambda-supports-10gb-memory-6-vcpu-cores-lambda-functions/) announcement. Note that not all AWS regions support this 10 GB of memory yet. For example, I tried setting memory to 10240 MB in Asia Pacific (Hong Kong) region, I got the same error.

Comment: I was already in a supported region (Frankfurt) when I entered this issue. I have created a copy of my Lambda in London just in case, but still the memory is limited to 3008 MB?

Comment: Yes, I guess it's region specific. No problem in Ireland, but still a problem in London.

Answer (score 4):

It seems new accounts have [restricted memory and concurrency quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html). From the docs:

"Important
New AWS accounts have reduced concurrency and memory quotas. AWS raises these quotas automatically based on your usage. You can also request a quota increase."

Answer (score 3):

I do have the same problem here. I am using a Python 3.8 runtime in Frankfurt (eu-central-1). I also checked with other runtimes and London (eu-west-2) - same error.

However if I create a function in Ireland (eu-west-1) or North Virginia (us-east-1) the limit is at the expected limit of 10240 MB. I assume that there are (temporary?) provisioning issues with the other regions.

Comment: I have this limit for us-east-1...